# How to increment an iterator by 2?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, iterator

Can anybody tell me how to increment the iterator by 2?

`iter++` is available - do I have to do `iter+2`? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Judging by the range of answers, you may need to clarify your question.

Comment: Yes. What kind of iterator is it? Show some code.

Answer (score 121):

[`std::advance( iter, 2 );`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

This method will work for iterators that are not random-access iterators but it can still be specialized by the implementation to be no less efficient than `iter += 2` when used with random-access iterators.

Comment: What will happen if the iterator currently points onto the last element? Where will it point after the increment? I tried with VC++ - it just advances and comparison against vector::end() returns false after that. This is straight way to undefined behaviour, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, if you're going to do std::advance with '2', or +=2, or two '++' without checking for 'end' in the middle, then you need some external guarantee that you're not going to go beyond one past the end. (E.g. you might *know* that you're iterating through the even numbered (zero based) items of a collection which is guaranteed to have an even number of items.)

Comment: what is difference between next( iter, 2) and next( iter, 2 )

Answer (score 37):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/

```
std::advance(it,n);
```

where n is 2 in your case.

The beauty of this function is, that If "it" is an random access iterator, the fast

```
it += n
```

operation is used (i.e. vector<,,>::iterator).   Otherwise its rendered to

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    ++it;
```

(i.e. list<..>::iterator)

Answer (score 35):

If you don't have a modifiable lvalue of an iterator, or it is desired to get a copy of a given iterator (leaving the original one unchanged), then C++11 comes with new helper functions - [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) / [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev):

```
std::next(iter, 2);          // returns a copy of iter incremented by 2
std::next(std::begin(v), 2); // returns a copy of begin(v) incremented by 2
std::prev(iter, 2);          // returns a copy of iter decremented by 2
```

Comment: If i have a an iterator like this:

`map<string,string>::iterator iter;
for(iter = variations.begin(); iter != variations.end(); iter++)
{
    map<string,string>::iterator it_tmp = std::next(iter, 1); // increment by 1
     it_tmp = std::next(iter, 2); // increment by 2
}`
Will **iter** be incremented by 2 ? or *iter* will just affect it_tmp?

Comment: @HaniGoc Only it_tmp

Answer (score 9):

You could use the 'assignment by addition' operator

```
iter += 2;
```

Comment: I was wondering if ++iter++ would work, but I think that would just be confusing.

Comment: What will happen if the iterator currently points onto the last element? Where will it point after the increment?

Comment: @Xetius: You should not do it. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: ++iter++ binds as ++(iter++), iter++ is not a modifiable lvalue so you can't 'do' ++(iter++). If it was allowed, it probably wouldn't do what might be expected of it.

Comment: This doesn't work for all iterator types. Only RandomAccessIterators are required to support addition.

Answer (score 9):

We can use both [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) as well as [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), but there's a difference between the two.

`advance` modifies its argument and returns nothing. So it can be used as:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
auto itr = v.begin();
advance(itr, 1);          //modifies the itr
cout << *itr<<endl        //prints 2
```

`next` returns a modified copy of the iterator:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
cout << *next(v.begin(), 1) << endl;    //prints 2
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know wether you have enough next elements in your container or not, you need to check against the end of your container between each increment. Neither ++ nor std::advance will do it for you.

```
if( ++iter == collection.end())
  ... // stop

if( ++iter == collection.end())
  ... // stop
```

You may even roll your own bound-secure advance function.

If you are sure that you will not go past the end, then std::advance( iter, 2 ) is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming list size may not be an even multiple of step you must guard against overflow:

```
static constexpr auto step = 2;

// Guard against invalid initial iterator.
if (!list.empty())
{
    for (auto it = list.begin(); /*nothing here*/; std::advance(it, step))
    {
        // do stuff...

        // Guard against advance past end of iterator.
        if (std::distance(it, list.end()) > step)
            break;
    }
}
```

Depending on the collection implementation, the distance computation may be very slow. Below is optimal and more readable. The closure could be changed to a utility template with the list end value passed by const reference:

```
const auto advance = [&](list_type::iterator& it, size_t step)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; it != list.end() && i < step; std::next(it), ++i);
};

static constexpr auto step = 2;

for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); advance(it, step))
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

If there is no looping:

```
static constexpr auto step = 2;
auto it = list.begin();

if (step <= list.size())
{
    std::advance(it, step);
}
```

Comment: What is the Time Complexity of "std::advance(it, step);".

Answer (score -9):

The very simple answer:

```
++++iter
```

The long answer:

You really should get used to writing `++iter` instead of `iter++`.  The latter must return (a copy of) the old value, which is different from the new value; this takes time and space.

Note that prefix increment (`++iter`) takes an lvalue and returns an lvalue, whereas postfix increment (`iter++`) takes an lvalue and returns an rvalue.

Comment: Undefined behavior if `iter` is a raw pointer (which some iterator types can be). `++it; ++it;` would be fine.

Comment: Please tell me this isn't a serious answer.