# `std::forward_list` walk until iterator is null?

Tags: c++11, traversal, nullptr, forward-list

Is it possible to walk a `std::forward_list`, incrementing an iterator, until said interator is null? The old-fashioned way...

In the following example, I create a `print()` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>

void print(std::forward_list<int>::iterator fl_it, std::forward_list<int>::iterator e) {

    while (fl_it != e) {
        std::cout << *fl_it  << ' ';
        ++fl_it;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;  //-> 1 2 3
}

int main() {
    std::forward_list<int> fl = {1, 2, 3};
    print(fl.begin(), fl.end());
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice how passing an iterator pointing to the end of the list is necessary, so that we know when to stop walking.

What I want to do is simply pass an iterator to the head of the list, and step along until there are no more elements, like so:

```
void print(std::forward_list<int>::iterator fl_it) {
    while (fl_it != nullptr) {
        std::cout << *fl_it << ' ';
        ++fl_it;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

My compiler doesn't like this `fl_it != nullptr` business.

My first inclination was to look for a method to check if the iterator is null, and references the end of the list. Sadly, such a method does not exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Think of it this way: If you had the first element of an array and no other information, could you get to the end?

Comment: And would you be able to *identify* the end when you came to it?

Comment: It should be noted that there *are* some kinds of iterators which *sort of* have this functionality--`std::istream_iterator` for one has an `istream&` constructor and a default constructor. The default-constructed iterator acts as the end iterator for the range, and the istream constructed iterator will compare equal with a default-constructed iterator when it encounters the end of the wrapped istream. So you could pass an `istream_iterator` into a function, and simply construct the end iterator inside it. But this doesn't apply for many types of iterators.

Comment: @AndyG, in an array, no, you need an argument count. A linked list is a different animal: we have the ability to set the pointer of the last node to a sentinel value.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

`std::forward_list` is a standard library container. Like all containers, it goes from `begin` to `end`. There are no "null" iterators. Operations therefore are on a range of iterators.

Note that the Range TS proposal intends to allow "sentinel" types instead of requiring end iterators. A single sentinel could compare equal to the end iterator of any range. So `forward_list` could indeed be updated to have such a value.

But it still wouldn't be a "null" iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You should realise that the iterator object is not exactly a pointer. It is an object and it represents the position of an item in a datastructure. 
Also incrementing the end iterator does not result in a null iterator. It is undefined behavior. Look at [Can an STL map iterator go out of bounds through incrementing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324790/can-an-stl-map-iterator-go-out-of-bounds-through-incrementing)

Answer (score 0):

The iterator is not null when at the end of the list, instead it is equal to the list's *end iterator* `fl.end()`. So both iterators need to be passed to the function.

The internal implementation of the iterator depends on the STL library used, for `std::forward_list` its interface is such that it fulfills the `ForwardIterator` concept: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator .

Comment: "both iterators need to be passed to the function" <-- seems sorta anti-thematic where forward linked lists are concerned, no? Aren't one-direction linked lists supposed to have an end marker? We're supposed to be able to march along until we hit the end of the line.

Comment: Internally `fl.end()` probably represents a sentinel value, and comparing it to the end iterator actually checks if a pointer is null (depending on how `std::forward_list` is implemented). But in STL for all container types, two iterators are always used to iterate through the list.