# Capitalizing letters

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, iterator, stdstring

I have got a small problem. I want to capitalize on doubled letters in a string. I managed to compile a program, but not successfully.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

std::string::iterator function(
   std::string::const_iterator a, 
   std::string::const_iterator b,
   std::string::const_iterator e)
{
   for (; a < b; a++) 
   {
      if (*a == *(a + 1)) 
      {
         toupper(*a);
         toupper(*(a + 1));
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   std::string in = "peppermint 1001 bubbles balloon gum", out(100, '*');
   auto e = function(in.cbegin(), in.cend(), out.begin());

   int n = e - out.begin();
   std::string s = out.substr(0, n);
   bool b = (s == "pePPermint 1001 buBBles baLLOOn gum");
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << b << std::endl;
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of issues there.

Firstly, your function promised to return `std::string::iterator`

```
std::string::iterator function(....)
{
  //... return statement is missing here!
}
```

and you are not keeping the promise. This will leads to ***[undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936011/if-a-function-returns-no-value-with-a-valid-return-type-is-it-okay-to-for-the)***.  For example, in your case, it just compiles and does not give the output.

In order to get a defined behaviour, you should return from the function

```
std::string::iterator function(...)
{
   // ... code
   return {}; // return appropriately iterator of std::string
}
```

---

Secondly, you want to modify the characters of the string, which requires a modifiable iterator rather than `std::string::const_iterator`.

Then in the loop, you need to alter the capitalized `char`ector by reassigning to it. For example:

```
*a = toupper(*a);
```

---

Thirdly, you should be careful about doing this in the for-loop of your function

```
 for(; a < b; a++)
 {
     if(*a == *(a + 1))  // --->here
     // ... code
 }
```

What would happen for the case when `a== str.end()-1`, you still would do the increment(i.e.  `*(a + 1)`), right?. Incrementing the end iterator again *[leads you Undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057724/what-happens-if-you-increment-an-iterator-that-is-equal-to-the-end-iterator-of-a)*.

In that case, you could use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) from `<iterator>` header to safely check this.

Following is the demonstrative code which clears the issues mentioned above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>  // std::next

std::string::iterator function(
   std::string::iterator a, 
   std::string::iterator b, 
   std::string::iterator e)
{
   auto beg = a;
   for (; a < b; a++)
   {
      if (std::next(a) != b && *a == *std::next(a)) {
         *a = toupper(*a);
         *std::next(a) = toupper(*std::next(a));
      }
   }
   std::cout << std::string{ beg, b };
   return {}; // return appropriately iterator of std::string
}
```

prints for now: https://godbolt.org/z/ZsLHxw

```
pePPermint 1001 buBBles baLLOOn gum
```

---

I assume that you want somehow to get the output to the third function parameter `std::string::iterator e`. I will let that part for you to figure it out. Meanwhile, have a look at the standard algorithm function [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), which might be handy to do such kind of transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Answers are already given. I want additionally to show an answer based on existing C++ functionality. For your given task there is a function existing in the C++ standard algorithm library. It is called `std::adjacent_find`. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

With that you could rewrite your code simply to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    std::string test{ "peppermint 1001 bubbles balloon gum" };

    // Find all duplicates
    for (auto il = std::adjacent_find(test.begin(), test.end()); il != test.end(); il = std::adjacent_find(il+1, test.end())) {
        
        // If duplicate found, then convert both to uppercase
        *il = std::toupper(*il);
        *(il + 1) = std::toupper(*(il+1));
    }
    std::cout << test << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

We call this function in a simple for loop, until no more duplicates could be found.

Maybe it can give you an idea for a more simple implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your function exhibits undefined behavior because it never returns a value.  Please compile with `-Wall -Wextra` to enable all compiler warnings to avoid such unnecessary bugs.