# vector::end() + 1 != vector::end()?

Tags: c++, stl

I thought `vector::end()` equals to any iterator beyond the vector size, but recently I realized that `end() + 1 != end()`.

I experimented further with the following code compiled by `g++`:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v(10);

    cout << (v.end() - v.begin()) << endl;     // 10
    cout << (v.end() + 1 - v.begin()) << endl; // 11
    cout << (v.end() + 1 == v.end()) << endl;  // false
    return 0;
}
```

It is like the iterator actually holds an array index under the hood.

So my question is: for `vector`, is this well-defined or compiler-dependent?

Comment: `end()` already points one beyond the last element.

Comment: Incrementing the `end()` iterator causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @asmmo You're confusing `end()` with an iterator to the last element, it seems. `end()` is already one element past the end of the container, dereferencing `end()` itself is UB.

Comment: Incrementing an end iterator (e.g.  `++end_iterator`) or adding `1` to an end iterator (e.g. `v.end() + 1` or (equivalently) advancing an end iterator by `1` (e.g. `std::advance(end_iterator, 1)`) all give undefined behaviour.      So both the second and third lines aren't guaranteed to produce the same result or output.

Comment: Thanks guys.  By using **incrementing** as a keyword, I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057788/3235047 .  The conclusion is: incrementing end() is UB.

Comment: Peter, BlackCat Thank u.