# Increment operator ++ does not seem to have same characteristics as +2

Tags: c++

I am busy with pointers at the moment and specifically pointers pointing to different elements in an array when I increment.

When I incremented using `++` everything is fine, but when I incremented using `+2` things turned out differently to what I expected.

Let me explain.

In the first instance I set `p2 = p1++;`. The result I got there was what I expected, ie. `p2` gives the value `2` and `p1` gives the value `3`. This is obviously since the initial value of `p1` is assigned to `p2` and afterwards `p1` is incremented by 1, giving a new value for `p1`. No problem with that.

However; in the second instance I set`p2 = p1+2`. The result I got was not what I expected. The result was `p1` gives value of `2` and `p2` gives value of `4`. How can this be? Shouldn't, like in the first instance, the initial value of `p1` have been assigned to `p2` , and then afterwards `p1` incremented by 2 and given a new value of `4`?

Then I got thinking a bit. Maybe `+2` and `++` have different characteristics. What I mean with this is that when using `++`, in this case, the code is saying (in layman's terms): "Make `p2`  point to the same address as `p1` did at the start, and then let `p1` point to the address of the next element". But when using `+2` the code is saying: "Go to the element two "blocks" down from `p1` and let `p2` point to the address of that specific element; BUT DON'T CHANGE THE ADDRESS `p1` IS POINTING TO WHILE DOING SO!". And this is what I mean with "they show different characteristics". They don't act in the same manner.

Is my assumption correct?

Also, how do you increment by two(or three or four, etc.) in this instance whilst maintaining the same characteristics as the `++` operator?

Here are some links to sites I researched which dealt with increments. But none of them really address my problem properly.  Nor do any other sites. Also, most of them suggest using something like `a +=2` to increment by two, which is fine, but that also does not tackle my specific problem.

[Link1](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/57856-incrementing-2-not-1-a.html)
[Link2 SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057529/how-to-increment-an-iterator-by-2)

Could you please explain in the simplest terms possible since I am still new to C++.

### Instance One

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p1, *p2;
    p1 = &a[1];
    p2 = p1++;
    std::cout << "Value1: " << *p1 << "\n" << "Value2: " << *p2;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output result of instance one (What I expected)

```
Value1: 3
Value2: 2
```

### Instance Two

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p1, *p2;
    p1 = &a[1];
    p2 = p1+2;
    std::cout << "Value1: " << *p1 << "\n" << "Value2: " << *p2;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output result of instance two (NOT what I expected)

```
Value1: 2
Value2: 4
```

Comment: In the second code snippet, you make `p1` point to the second element in the array. Then you make `p2` point to the *fourth* element (index 1 + 2) in the array, so the output is what should be expected. It might be clearer if you know that `a[X]` is equivalent to `*(a + X)` (meaning `&a[X]` is equivalent to `a + X`).

Comment: Fyi:  ++ == +1*sizeof

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah, I got it now. Rerito , below cleared things up for me. Like I told him;  I do understand the differences between the + and ++ operator. It's just that in this case the tut I was using led me to falsely believe that the +2 was just an extension of the ++ operator. It didn't really explain that it was merely an arithmetic operation and not an increment. it would have been better had they maybe put a space between the "+" and the "2". Then it would immediately have been clear to me what was happening.

Comment: ps. I wonder why all the down votes, though. Can't really see what was so wrong about the question.

Comment: @AK_ Not quite sure what you mean there.

Comment: 1) It's `#include`, not `#Include`. 2) Please indent your code properly. For simple code it may be readable but for more complex codes it will be impossible to recognize which statement belongs to which scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is exactly what is expected. When you perform this assignment:

```
p2 = p1 + 2;
```

You just ask to assign the value `p1 + 2` to `p2`, that's it. There is no reason for `p1` being updated. You seem to confuse the `+` operator with the post-increment/pre-increment `++` operator.

[A little reminder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Arithmetic_operators) might help.

Comment: Alright. I got it now. I understand the differences between the + and ++ operator. It's just that in this case the tut I was using led me to falsely believe that the +2 was just an extension of the ++ operator. It didn't really explain that it was merely an arithmetic operation and not an increment. it would have been better had they maybe put a space between the "+" and the  "2". Then it would immediately have been clear to me what was happening. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 3):

`p2 = p1+2;` does *not* modify the value of `p1`. It just assigns the result of `p1+2` to `p2`.

`p2 = p1++;` *does* modify the value of `p1`. It first assigns `p1` to `p2`, then increments `p1` by one.

Comment: Yeah, zenith. I got it now. Thanks, mate.